# will cmake build type RelWithDebInfo strip symbol table?

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake

I was building a shared library  using cmake with `RelWithDebInfo` build type, the output .so file has no symbol table.

I inspect the output .so file with `readelf -S myoutput.so | grep -i debug` with gives me nothing.

If I change the build type to `Debug`, the symbol table is there.

I suppose `RelWithDebInfo` is equivalent to `-O2 -g`, which should be able to reserver debug symbol. There must be something wrong in my CMakeList.txt......but it's a very large project I don't have a clear where to look at, any idea or hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, I've figured out the problem. I was using pybind11 for my project, and pybind11 internally strip unneeded symbols.